# List of Integers

Tags: mathematica-online

Evan writes down a list of 15 integers, each of which is either 0 or 1. He does this in such a way that there are never three consecutive integers in the list that have the same value. How many ways are there for Evan to do this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no work.  And has nothing to do with the *Mathematica* programming language.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Mathematica :-).
Not sure whether I got the point, but I would suggest:

```
DeleteCases[Tuples[{0, 1}, 15], {___, x_, x_, x_, ___}] // Length
```

Which is to get all sequences and delete those that are not wanted (three consecutive numbers).